# Tracing Remote Sql Execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Recently in our database server we have found that there are some queries executed by unknown client/user/application. We have found out the query client_name is the name of the same server (means local) and client_application_name is *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query*.

How can we make sure that which user or applictaion executed these queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure, because the database only can report what information the client is sharing - which may be fake.  But if you know the connection has been made from the database server itself, it can't be hard to find out what programs were running at that time.